# Easy Way to Find Images Used in a Wordpress Post?

Tags: wordpress

Is there anything in the wordpress APIs which will show me a list of images used in a post? Or do I need to look through the content of the post to find this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, once again i ask a question before thoroughly looking for an answer. A quick google search turned up the following snippet of code:

```
$arrImages =& get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . $iPostID );
```

I found this at http://wphackr.com/.